# discord.py wikipedia search command does not reply

Tags: discord, wikipedia, discord.py, wikipedia-api

When I try to run my cog it gives an error "No value for argument 'arg' in function call'. Can someone help please?

````
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import os
import datetime
import random
import wikipedia


class wiki(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Wikipedia Cog has been loaded\n-----")

    @commands.command()
    async def wiki(self,ctx,word):
        def viki_sum(self,arg):
            definition = wikipedia.summary(arg,sentences=3,chars=1000)
            return definition
        embed = discord.Embed(title="***Wiki'de Bulduklarım:***",description=viki_sum(word))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(wiki(bot))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!

It seems that the error you are getting comes from this section of the code:

```py
@commands.command()
async def wiki(self, ctx, word):
    def viki_sum(self, arg):
        definition = wikipedia.summary(arg, sentences=3, chars=1000)
        return definition
```

The `viki_sum` function is a nested function. Even though its enclosing function is a class method and requires using `self` as the first argument, any nested functions do not require that argument.

So, to overcome the error, you need to remove the `self` argument from the `viki_sum` function.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you, i have one more question. How can i redirect the user when he press on the text?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have any experience with discord.py, but after a bit of googling, I found that you can send the text like this `[text](link)` - it adds a link to the text, effectively redirecting the user when they press on it ([reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/882fek/how_can_i_make_a_clickable_text_link_thing_like/dwhx1sk/))

Comment: yea, i know it but i can't find how to find this articles link, any idea about it?